# How to make the down arrow work on input search box?

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have a input on my page where I am asking the user to type in any value and based on his entry the values are displayed from the database.

For example if the user types `p` in the input box he is displayed *programmer 1* and *programmer 2* just as it does in *google.com*. This I am doing through ajax.

My problem is after *programmer 1* and *programmer 2* is displayed, the <kbd>↓</kbd> Down Arrow key doesn't bring the control to the *programmer 1* but rather keeps the control on the search box and the user has to click on any of these options. I want the user to be able to use the <kbd>↓</kbd> down arrow key to come down to his search suggestions.

I have tried to implement `Focus` functions but it doesn't seem to work and I don't really know how to look for this information?

Code:

```
<input type="text" name="searchbox" class="search_input" id="searchboxid" autocomplete="off" autofocus="on" onkeyup="suggest(this.value)" placeholder="Please search here..."/>
```

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: This Javascript not php, but a second ..

Comment: Oh yes, Javascript. I am making the website in PHP though. Thanks. Any help?

Comment: yes i'm working something out, but i'm at work, going slower ;)

Comment: What are you using to autosuggest?

Comment: I am using the value the user inputs in the input box and fetch all the values starting from it from the database (SQL). I am using the following function:-

    function suggest(inputString)
  {
  if(inputString.length == 0) 
   {
    $('#suggestions').fadeOut();
   } 
  else 
   {
    $.post("autosuggest.php",       {queryString: ""+inputString+""}, 
    function(data)
    { 
    if(data.length >0) 
     {
      $('#suggestions').fadeIn();
      $('#suggestionsList').html(data);
     }     
    });
   } 
  } `

Answer (score 1):

Just a suggestion.
Instead of fighting with your own code or going for keybinding stuffs. Its better to use jquery autocomplete.You can easily port your code to fit with Jquery auto complete.Its giving the option what you are expecting.
Refer the URL below.
http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/

Comment: Hi Samy,

Thank you so much for this suggestion, it is a wonderful idea and i am currently trying to implement it. The only problem i am facing is that i am unable to enter the html(data) into the array.

Comment: You are talking about which array?

Answer (score 0):

Try with autosuggest or with autocomplete on. If none works , try key binding via hex code for down arrow. It is little dark , but it works in many cases , only prob could be AV's , which could recognise it as a keylogger.

Comment: @Samy , great idea , I used this method for long time and it worked , until web based keyloggers came to scene.

Answer (score 0):

Oke short tell: i'll put in code later (15 minuts)

Html:

```
<input type=""text id="r0">
<div id="r1">the damn results</div>
<div id="r2">another dman result</div>
```

Jquery:

```
$("body").keydown(function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 38) {  //up-arrow

//check wich one is focus
//?????
//r
        if ($("#" + rId).length > 0) {
            //focus on this element
        }
    }

    if (e.keyCode == 40) {  //down-arrow

//check wich one is focus
//?????
//r
        if ($("#" + rId).length > 0) {
            //focus on this element
        }
    }
});
```

Raw i will work it out in a second